# Goldbach conjecture and the representation number

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbach-type-problems

Let $g(2n)$ be the number of representations of $2n=p+q$ with primes $p$ and $q$. Many people have asked whether $g(2n) \ge 2$ when $2n = p+q$ for some primes $p$ and $q$. That is, does $g(2n) \ge 1$ imply $g(2n) \ge 2$? From the famous [Goldbach Comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_comet), it looks probable although it was not yet proved.

Now, what can we say about the following weaker problem?

> For any sufficiently large prime $p$, is there a prime $q$ such that $p+q$ has another representation $p' + q'$?

Comment: Conjecturally yes, but it's not been proved, as far as I know.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Tur%C3%A1n_conjecture_on_additive_bases

Comment: Please always include a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory".

Comment: @GHfromMO I forgot it. Thank you for your editing.

Comment: Strictly formally speaking, if (p,q) is a solution, (q,p) is another solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To your first question: we don't know. To your second question: we know much more, namely if $N$ is a large odd number, then the number of representations $N=p_1+p_2-p_3$ with each $p_j$ a prime from $[2N,3N]$, has order of magnitude $N^2/(\log N)^3$. This can be proved in essentially the same way as we prove that $N$ can be written as a sum of three primes in that many ways. See also Harald Helfgott's response [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202979/a-variant-of-the-goldbach-conjecture/202982#202982).

Answer (score 7):

Here is a graph showing the number of representations of $2n$ as a sum of two primes.

[image]

It suggests that something much stronger than what you ask about is true. And there are heuristics that predict what is shown. but not proofs.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n \in 2\mathbb{N}^*$ large enough.

$$n = p+q, \ (p,q)\in\mathbb{P}^2 \iff (p, n-p) \in \mathbb{P}^2$$

You search for the quantative version of **Goldbach's conjecure**, Hardy and Littlewood in there 1923 paper "*Some problems of ‘Partitio
numerorum’; III : On the expression of a number as a sum of primes*", conjecture that :
$$G(n) \sim 2 C_2 \displaystyle {\small \Big( \prod_{\substack{p | n \\ \text{p prime} \\ 3 \leqslant p}} {\normalsize \dfrac{p-1}{p-2}} \Big)} \dfrac{n}{\log(n)^2}.$$

Where $G(n) = \#\{(p, n-p) \in \mathbb{P}^2 \, | \, p \leqslant n\}$, and : $C_2 = \displaystyle{\small \prod_{\substack{3 \leq p \\ \text{p prime}}} \left({\normalsize 1-\dfrac{1}{(p-1)^2}}\right)}$.

This conjecture agree perfectely with numeric checks, but unfortunately not proven up to now (and no hope to prove it soon).

You can see my try here : [is there a link with the probabilistic model for prime numbers?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350270/is-there-a-link-with-the-probabilistic-model-for-prime-numbers)

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question that was asked

Comment: @YemonChoi, he ask if $g(2n) \ge 1 \implies g(2n) \ge 2$, and i say that $g(2n)$ is more much bigger (conjectured), please delete your comment you made a mistake.

Comment: The OP mentions that conjecture, but he or she is asking about "the following weaker problem". See the answer of GHfromMO. Please read carefully the question being asked

Comment: I understund exactly his 2 questions, the second about fixing a prime number $p$, then for every other prime number $3 \leqslant q \leqslant p$, we have $n_{p,q}=p+q$ is an even number and returning to Goldbach's conjecture on it's quantative form we have approximatly $G(n_{p, q})$ representation of $n_{p,q}$ as sum of 2 primes.